# TypeError: $(...).typed is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement this typed.js to my site and have a trouble with jquery

Firebug shows two errors:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

    <!DOCTYPE html> <br>
    typed.js (line 1)

TypeError: $(...).typed is not a function <br>

    $(".typing").typed({<br>
    mydomain.com (line 74)
```

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Javascript --> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/typed.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $(".typing").typed({
            strings: ["Typed.js is a <strong>jQuery</strong> plugin.", "It <em>types</em> out sentences.", "And then deletes them.", "Try it out!"],
            typeSpeed: 30,
            backDelay: 500,
            loop: false,
            contentType: 'html', // or text
            // defaults to false for infinite loop
            loopCount: false,
            callback: function(){ foo(); },
            resetCallback: function() { newTyped(); }
        });
        $(".reset").click(function(){
            $("#typed").typed('reset');
        });
    });
    function newTyped(){ /* A new typed object */ }
    function foo(){ console.log("Callback"); }
    </script>
```

It is set in the end, before body tag

As I understood there is a conflict between 2 jquery libraries, but i am quiet new to this, so can't understand how to fix it.

Please help me)

Comment: Fix that `<!DOCTYPE html> <br>` and it should work. But that's quite strange issue, your javascript file is invalid, use a relevant one

Comment: From the error, it looks like `typed.js` contains HTML ?

Comment: OMG! Thanks!the file was corrupted, now everything is good!